# Android: Any special permission (other than INTERNET) required for running TCP server

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

Do we need any other special permission other than [INTERNET](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET), for running TCP server in android app ?

Comment: Have you tried? You got problems? Exceptions? Stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using sockets, I don't think you're going to need other permissions.